# Remove extra empty space from ngx-datatable header

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-datatable

I am creating a ngx-datatable but getting extra space at header of table.Also the data-rows are not aligned to header due to this header only.This extra space is coming at the both end of table.

I need to remove the marked space in the image below:
[image: Data-Table]

**HTML:**

```
<ngx-datatable class='bootstrap' columnMode="force"  [headerHeight]="30" [selectionType]="'multiClick'"
    [rows]="rows">

    <ngx-datatable-column name="UserName"  prop = "UserName" headerClass="mydata-table-header">
    </ngx-datatable-column>

      <ngx-datatable-column name="Date" prop = "Date" headerClass="mydata-table-header" >
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Activity" prop="Activity" headerClass="mydata-table-header" ></ngx-datatable-column>

      <ngx-datatable-column name="Decision" prop="Activity" headerClass="mydata-table-header" >
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Remark" prop="Activity" headerClass="mydata-table-header">

      </ngx-datatable-column>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap {
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  border:none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header {
  height: unset !important;
  background-color:#28998b;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header .datatable-header-cell {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header .datatable-header-cell .datatable-header-cell-label {
  line-height: 24px;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body {

}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row.datatable-row-even {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row .datatable-body-cell {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row.active {
  background-color: #1483ff;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css file would look like:

```
.datatable-header {
   height: unset !important;
}

.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header .datatable-header-cell {
   vertical-align: bottom;
   padding: 0.0rem !important;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   background-color:#28998b;
}

.ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body .datatable-body-row .datatable-body-cell {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You could need to adjust the values in padding: 0.0rem.

Also make sure your customised css is the last line in the styleUrls metadata:

```
styleUrls: [
   '../../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/bootstrap.css',
   './your.component.css'
]
```

Comment: This is not working, I have the same problem too, need a help please with it.

Comment: @Tarek what problem are you having?

Answer (score 0):

If you use angular (it works but it's a kind of HACK!):

```
:host ::ng-deep .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header,
:host ::ng-deep .datatable-header {
    height: 30px !important; // set the height of the header
}

:host ::ng-deep .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-header .datatable-header-cell {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px !important; // align the header text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following propertyes at the ngx-datatable-column tag:

```
[width]="150"
[height]="100"
[canAutoResize]="false"
```

That's simpler than using css classes, but you still can create your css class, up to you, hope this help who's in doubt.